# React Native useState doesn't update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

From my Api I am getting array of Objects like this:

```
[{
"category_param": {"id": 2, "name": "sport"}, 
"id": 2, "isSelect": false, "name": "temperature"
}, 
.........
{
"category_param": {"id": 1, "name": "food"}, 
"id": 99, "isSelect": false, "name": "location"
}]
```

After I get this data from Api, I am store it using useState. In **data** to work with it, and **dataInit** to save clean unfiltered data from Api:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [dataInit, setDataInit] = useState([]);
```

and on my screen I am outputs this **data**, and everything works well.
But,
I have on my screen filter buttons, that should filter my list by **category_param.id**:

```
     <TouchableOpacity
        key={0}
        accessibilityRole="button"
        onPress={() => onPress('')}
        >
        <Text>
          All
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={2}
        accessibilityRole="button"
        onPress={() => onPress(2)}
        >
        <Text>
          Sport
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={1}
        accessibilityRole="button"
        onPress={() => onPress(1)}
        >
        <Text>
          Food
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

And my onPress function is:

```
const onPress = id => {
    setData(dataInit); //Line #1
    if (id === '') {
      setData(dataInit); //Line #2
      return;
    }

    console.log('BEFORE TAB FILTER:::', data); //Line #3
    let filtered = data(item => {
      return item.category_param.id === id;
    });
    setData(filtered);//Line #4
    console.log('filtered:::', filtered);//Line #5
  };
```

So, the problem is when I press on **Sport button (id=2)** or **Food button (id=1)** exactly after my screen opens, it filters and on my screen **data** is filtered. When I after that click on **All button (id='')**, I see **dataInit (//Line #2)** - my all clean data from Api.

But when I click after my screen opens on **Sport button (id=2)**, and then on **Food button (id=1)**, result is empty, because as I see from **console log //Line #3** - after first click on button, here is my **initData**, but after second click **console log on //Line #3** not returns **data**, it returns my **filtered data**, that was set on **//Line #4** after first click.

Is there any way to make **setData(dataInit); //Line #1** works and put in **data** clean list form Api every time I click on any filter button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be because of by clicking on **Sport button** you set your **data** to filtered data (as on `let filtered = data(item => { return item.category_param.id === id; });`), so, on next clicking to **Food button** you trying to filter already filtered data. **setData** in your case doesn't set your **data** to default instantly.

If you have already saved init data, so, maybe you should just filter it, instead of setting data to default and trying to filter it (useless code as I think). If you have questions, you could write me :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how I can setData to my default state? I also saving default data in dataInit and I thought that setData(dataInit); //Line #1 should set my data to default data.

Comment: It should, but not instantly. I could suggest you to do something like that `const onPress = id => {
    if (id === '') {
      setData(dataInit); //Line #2
      return;
    }

    console.log('BEFORE TAB FILTER:::', data); //Line #3
    let filtered = dataInit(item => {
      return item.category_param.id === id;
    });
    setData(filtered);//Line #4
    console.log('filtered:::', filtered);//Line #5
  };`

Comment: It will not mutate your default dataInit, but will be used everytime to filter your data (there is no reason in that case to setData to default everytime before filtering, if you have default to check).

Comment: I rewrite my code are you says and now it works. Thanks =)